# Swift function vs lazy var vs computed property - difference?

Tags: swift

Is there a difference between following:

Lazy variable:

```
lazy var profileImageIsLoaded : Bool = {
    return (profileImageView.image != nil) && (profileImageProgressView.alpha == 0.0)
}()
```

Function:

```
func profileImageIsLoaded() -> Bool {
    return (profileImageView.image != nil) && (profileImageProgressView.alpha == 0.0)
}
```

Computed Property:

```
var profileImageIsLoaded : Bool {
    return (profileImageView.image != nil) && (profileImageProgressView.alpha == 0.0)
}
```

and what method would be the best to use?

I would call the function/variable multiple times, so my question is also whether lazy vars are "updated" or whether they only get a value one time.

Comment: lazy vars are assigned only once, when the value is accessed for the first time. Computed variables are calculated everytime you access them. Function is a more complex version of a computed variable, you can pass parameters, assign to local properties, etc.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

- `lazy var`s are actually *stored* properties, so you can't put it in extensions or anywhere stored properties are not allowed.
- The getter for computed properties is run *every time* you refer to that property. This can be significant especially if the getter is time-consuming or has side-effects to other parts of the code.
- The getter for `lazy var`s are only run when the property is first referred to and never again.
- `lazy var`s are *variables*. You can mutate them.
- Computed properties can *optionally* have a setter, so sometimes they are read-only.
- Using a function like that is very similar to a read only computed property. You just have to add `()` when getting its value.

Comment: Do optional lazy vars exist and what would they do, or is that a whole other topic?

Comment: @T.Meyer they are just lazy vars, except they are of an optional type. The difference is that you can return `nil` in the closure.

Comment: @t-meyer : You would use lazy var when you want initialize the variable only once in its entire life cycle. Assume you wanna set up NSFetchedResultsController, you want it to be initialized only once through out the entire life cycle of ViewController, in such situation you could use lazy var. If you dont use lazy var you would have if condition checking if variable was every initialized or not like the one we had in objective C lazy var is clean and simpler work around

Comment: One other important thing to note about lazy variables is that they are not thread safe.  If two threads try to access the lazy variable at the same time and it can result in it being calculated twice.

Comment: @Sweeper: +1 for the correct information. I still have one doubt that which one is more efficient in terms of compilation?

Comment: @Kampai what kind of thing are you developing where compilation time matters?

Comment: @Sweeper: I have very big iOS app in swift, which is developed by other developer, there are so many extensions with many computed properties, lazy vars, and functions. It takes more than 2 mins to compile the project. I am reducing the compile time now. Can you please help me to understand which is better?

Comment: @Kampai are you sure the long compile time is due to lazy vars/computed properties? It could be due to the fact that your source code is _inherently long_. From my experience, complicated expressions can cause long compile times as well.

Comment: @Sweeper: Yes, it is. I am looking for all possible ways to make it less. But to make it best practice I am hoping that extensions can be improved.

Comment: @Sweeper: Which is better? `extension String {
    var localize : String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self.description, comment: "")
    }
    func LocalizedString() -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self.description, comment: "")
    }
}` The function or computed property?

Comment: @Kampai I would write a property named `localised`, not because its faster to compile, but because it is aesthetically pleasing to me, and it follows [Swift naming conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)

Answer (score 35):

The first one:

```
lazy var profileImageIsLoaded: Bool = {
    return (profileImageView.image != nil) && (profileImageProgressView.alpha == 0.0)
}()
```

`profileImageIsLoaded` is a stored property that is initialized lazily using a closure, once the variable has been initialized this closure will not be called anymore and the value it took the first time the closure was called will be returned.

The second one:

```
func profileImageIsLoaded() -> Bool {
    return (profileImageView.image != nil) && (profileImageProgressView.alpha == 0.0)
}
```

Is a normal function declaration, this is declaration only. If you wanted to call that function you'll do that like this: `profileImageIsLoaded()`.

The third one:

```
var profileImageIsLoaded: Bool {
    return (profileImageView.image != nil) && (profileImageProgressView.alpha == 0.0)
}
```

`profileImageIsLoaded` is a computed property, each time you access this property, it will be computed and returned.

Choosing which one to use always depends on your situation.

Comment: Really nice explanation

Comment: I'm glad it helped you!