# What is the difference between "lazy var funcName: () -> Void" and regular function declaration in Swift

Tags: swift

I have recently encountered such code block when I was working on a different codebase.

I was wondering is there any significant difference (in terms of memory impact etc.) between these two declarations other than syntactic ease? I regularly use lazy stored properties but I couldn't visualize how a function can be "lazy". Can you guys also enlighten me how functions are processed (or share an article explaining this topic) by the swift compiler as well?

[image]

Thanks in advance, wish you bug free codes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift function vs lazy var vs computed property - difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050058/swift-function-vs-lazy-var-vs-computed-property-difference)

Comment: @MacUserT How does that answer the question at all? A computed property is totally different from a function.

Comment: Please [edit] so that your code is posted as text, not an image.

Comment: @weeper, It answers the difference between a lazy var, a function and a computed property. So, a bit more than you asked for.

Comment: Ah I see. You interpreted this post in a different way than I did then. So you think this post is asking the difference between a function and a lazy var, in the specific case of a parameterless, void-returning function, while I took it to be a more general question, asking about the differences of the two ways of declaring function-like things in Swift.

Comment: @MacUserT but even if so, that post is still not a duplicate of the suggested dupe target. Notice that in Emircan Aydin's code, the closure for the lazy var is not invoked with `()`. OP here is not trying to create a lazy value that is lazily computed by a function. They are simply trying to write a void-returning function (and shows two ways of doing so) - no values involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're implementing a language, the magic you need to implement 'lazy' as a feature is to make the value provided silently be wrapped in a function (of no arguments) that is automatically evaluated the first time the property is read.

So for example if you have

```
var x = SomeObject() // eagerly construct an instance of SomeObject
```

and

```
lazy var x = SomeObject() // construct an instance if/when someone reads x
```

behind the scenes you have, for the `lazy var x`, either `x` has not yet been read, or it has been and therefore has a value.  So this is like

```
  enum Lazy<T> {
      case notReadYet(() -> T) // either you have a function that makes the initial T
      case read(T) // or you have a value for T
  }

 var thing: Lazy<SomeObject> = .notReadYet { return SomeObject() }
```

and with a suitable property wrapper or other language magic, wrap the calls to *the getter for thing* with a switch on the case, which checks if you are in the `notReadYet` case, and if so automatically invoke the function to produce the `T` and then set the property to `.read(t)` for the particular value of `t`.

If you substitute in your type: `() -> Void` from your example you have something like:

```
 var thing: Lazy<() -> Void> = .notReadYet({ return { print("Hello") } })
```

This is all rather odd because it's a `void` value and not much point making it lazy, e.g. it's not expensive to compute; it doesn't help break a two-phase initialisation loop, so why do it?

Answer (score 1):

A few differences I can think of off the top of my head:

- With functions, you can use parameter labels to make the call site more readable, but since you can't add parameter labels to function types, you can't do that with the `lazy var` declaration.

  ```
    // doesn't work
    lazy var say: (message: String, to person: String) -> Void = {
        ...
    }

    // works
    func say(message: String, to person: String) {
        ...
    }
  ```

  You can only invoke a function type with no parameter labels at all :( `say("Hello", "Sweeper")` instead of `say(message: "Hello", to: "Sweeper")`.
- `lazy var`s are variables, so someone could just change them:

  ```
    helloFunc = { /* something else */ }
  ```

  you could prevent this by adding a private setter, but that still allows setting it from within the same class. With a function, its implementation can never be changed at runtime.
- `lazy var`s cannot be generic. Functions can.

  ```
    // doesn't work
    lazy var someGenericThing<T>: (T) -> Void = {
        ...
    }

    // works
    func someGenericThing<T>(x: T) {
        ...
    }
  ```

  You might be able to work around this by making the enclosing type generic, but that changes the semantics of the entire type. With functions, you don't need to do that at all.

Comment: i agree with what you said. but you told me the difference between the two definitions. What I'm really curious about is how functions are handled in memory.