# Decodable with extra property

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I have a `Decodable` to which I want to add one extra property, not present in the plist.

The code below seems to work. I'm not sure why, since it no longer conforms to the plist. Can anyone explain?

Is there any better of doing it ***without*** having to write a custom `init` and `CodingKeys`?

```
struct Phrases: Decodable {
  let animal: Dictionary<String, String>
  let clothes: Dictionary<String, String>
  let food: Dictionary<String, String>
  let color: Dictionary<String, String>
}

extension Phrases {
  var nouns: Dictionary<String, String> {
    var nouns = [String: String]()
    nouns += self.animal
    nouns += self.clothes
    nouns += self.food
    return nouns
  }
}

extension Dictionary {
  static func += (left: inout Dictionary, right: Dictionary) {
    left.merge(right) { $1 }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand what the problem is here, better than what? What needs to be improved or fixed?

Comment: Your extra property is a read-only **computed** property which is ignored by the decoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This new property that you have added is a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259), not a stored property like `animal`, `food`, etc

The synthesised `Decodable` implementation is only derived from the stored properties of the struct, so adding a computed property does not change the synthesised `Decodable` implementation at all.

This is because the semantics of computed property is that its value is *computed* every time you access it (call its getter). Every time you say `nouns`, the code in the body runs, creating a new dictionary by *computing* the merge of the two dictionaries. This is as if it were just a function:

```
func nouns() -> Dictionary<String, String> {
    var nouns = [String: String]()
    nouns += self.animal
    nouns += self.clothes
    nouns += self.food
    return nouns
}
```

If that is the semantics you want, then doing this is not problematic at all.

---

Alternatively, if you want the semantics of a stored property, you can add `CodingKeys` (but no need for a custom `init(from:)`) and use a lazy var:

```
lazy var nouns: [String: String] = {
    ...
}()

enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case animal, food, color, clothes
}
```

However, this makes `nouns` mutable, which may not be desirable. To make `nouns` a stored property *and* a `let`, I'm pretty sure you have to write a custom `init(from:)`.

See more differences between this and a computed property in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48050106/5133585).

Comment: Thank you! I guess, given the fact that I don't want to write a custom `init` and `CodingKeys`, a computed property is the way to go.

Comment: I tried to keep my code as concise as possible, but I should've added an extra property, since that'll probably change your answer somewhat. I also added the Dictionary extension.

Comment: @Daan I don't think it changes the main points of my answer, except the simplification with `merging` doesn't work so well anymore.

Comment: Yeah, true. Thanks. I’m still trying to grasp the basic concepts and this really helps.